# How to increase shipping amount for UPS & FEDEX in magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, fedex, ups

I need to increase the calculated shipping amount in magento for ups & fedex.How can i do it?Is there anything we have to change in admin section while enabling shipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a handling fee for Fedex and UPS in the configuration for those shipping options. It can be either a fixed amount or a percentage.